# Non-English IE9 and CSS opacity

Tags: css, localization, internet-explorer-9, opacity

Look at the HTML code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="opacity:0.5">Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On English IE9 things go as expected and the "Hello World" div is shown with the desired (50%) opacity, but on German IE9 the div is hidden and by reviewing the DOM in the "F12 developer tools" I can see that the opacity evaluates to 0 instead of 0.5. Moreover after assigning any other value with a fractional part to the opacity property causes the latter to evaluate to the integer part only ignoring the fractional part (i.e. opacity:22.34 evaluates to 22). Any idea what can be the difference between the English IE9 and the German IE9 causing this strange CSS behavior and how can I work around it  (IMPORTANT: I don't want to use the alternative properties like filter:alpha or -ms-filter etc.)?

Comment: I'd try using `opacity: 0,5` (with a comma) as a workaround (there once existed a similar bug in Chrome).

Comment: Are you sure it's the same version number? Are you testing in the same browser/document mode?

Comment: I already tried using opacity:0,5 (with a comma) - it didn't help. In addition, on both browsers I use IE9 Browser mode and IE9 Standard document mode.

Comment: Probably won't fix it but if you use html5 doctype the `<html>` tag does not require  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange behaviour :S

The only idea I can think is about the decimal mark used in German and in English. In english it's a dot (`0.5`) and in german is a comma (`0,5`). You can try to put the comma to see what it happens. But if this is the problem, it's very very strange, because I suppose the notation depends on the CSS specification and not from the decimal mark used in each country. And I suppose as well that both IE share same core and there is only a L10n (localization) change.

Or look if both IE are exactly the same version (not only 9, but 9.whatever). Maybe is a bug in some version.

Comment: CSS spec doesn't change based on localization. It's not `colour:` in the UK, for example, and punctuation rules still follow the standards used in normal CSS/JS/whatever. Otherwise, you could never optimize for foreign visitors.

Comment: Both IE are of the "9.0.8112.16421" version with the "9.0.4 KB2618444" update. The only difference is the ProductID: English: 03553-918-5000002-85819, German: 03553-007-1403402-86915

Comment: Sorry then, no idea then which can be the problem... Did you clear browser cache when you changed the dot for the comma? I know what specification says @Nix, but at least duri says that this bug existed in Chrome once...

Comment: Changing the dot to the comma didn't help to show the element but it had another effect - it completely removed the 'opacity' property from the style list of the F12 developer tools - that means that IE9 didn't accept this syntax at all.

Comment: The bug is not present in Finnish version of IE 9 (which has exactly the same version and update number as shown above). So I guess this is a bug specific to the German version. @Moshe can you test whether German IE 9 otherwise works in standards mode? I mean it might be saying it’s in IE 9 Standard document mode but actually works in IE 8 document mode (at least partially).

Comment: As far as I can see, other features requiring IE9 standard mode (i.e. the DOM addEventListener method) seem to work as expected.

Comment: Another observation: this behavior has sporadic nature - sometimes (same static page) German IE9 does evaluate the opacity as expected (and then the value appears as "comma separated" in the F12 developer tools (reasonably)).